# PHP regular expression to remove duplicate child tags but keep parent and content

Tags: php, regex

I'm quite poor in regular expression,it would be a big time saver if I could get your help.

Are there any way to use preg_replace to return the output from input below:

### input

```
w1 <strong>w2</strong> w3 w4 <strong><strong>w5 <strong>w6</strong></strong></strong> w7
```

### output

```
w1 <strong>w2</strong> w3 w4 <strong>w5 w6</strong> w7
```

My purpose is to eliminate all duplicate inner child tag but keep the parent and its content.
Both resulted in html rendered like this (so I'm trying to make the tag cleaner):

w1 **w2** w3 w4 ****w5 **w6****** w7

w1 **w2** w3 w4 **w5 w6** w7

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this expression isn't regular. thus cannot be matched with a regex.

Comment: Could you add your attempts ? Maybe we could show you where you made a mistake.

Comment: @HuangTao You seem to be right, as I try to find the quick way with regex but no luck

Comment: @HamZa my attempt is similar to Babar's answer, the issue is with the tags with the words between

Comment: @Chanon Is this only limited to `strong` tags or do you have a list of tags or do you want something "dynamic". Note that dynamic is really difficult to achieve, I mean you might remove `div` tags. On another note, is there any chance to encounter something like `<strong style="font-size:16px">` ?

Comment: @HamZa it's only limited to strong, there will not be tag attribute (e.g. strict to pure like <tag>xxxx</tag>) Thanks for follow up :)

Comment: @Chanon Check this [regex](http://regex101.com/r/iI5gU7) out. Such regex, very complicated, good match, [wow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doge_(meme)) ! This is how you would use [the code in php](https://eval.in/124278). This is just experimental. Let's see if someone could come up with a DOM solution.

Comment: @HamZa Thanks heaps mate. For the wise solution and for doing this just to help. Your code working perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

### Worked with the solution from @HamZa

```
function remove_duplicate_child_tag($input, $tag = 'strong'){

    $pattern = "~
<{$tag}\s*>                         # Match strong open tag
(                                   # Open group 1
    (?:                             # Non-capturing group
        (?:(?!</?strong\s*>).)      # Match anything that not strong tag (open/close)
        |                           # Or
        (?R)                        # Repeat the whole pattern
    )*                              # Repeat the non-capturing group zero or more times
)                                   # Close group 1
</{$tag}\s*>                        # Match strong close tag
~xs";

    $output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m, $tag = 'strong'){
        return "<{$tag}>" . preg_replace("~</?{$tag}\s*>~", '', $m[1]) . "</{$tag}>";
    }, $input);

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'w1 <strong>w2</strong> w3 w4 <strong><strong>w5 <strong>w6</strong></strong></strong> w7';
$filtered_array = preg_replace('/(\<[a-zA-Z\/]+\>)+/', '$1', $str);
```

This will match and replace child HTML tags.

Comment: You don't need to escape `<>`.

Comment: This doesn't work, the output return
w1 <strong>w2</strong> w3 w4 <strong>w5 <strong>w6</strong> w7

it remove the continued tags (e.g. <strong><strong>), however, do not remove tags with words between (e.g. <strong>w5 <strong>)